# MVC displaying related child entities in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, eager-loading

I am trying to build a view in an MVC 4 app that will show a domain model and all the data from it's related child entities as well but for some reason, I cannot access the childrens' properties in the view. Intellisense does not see them.

Here is my domain model called Subscribers:

```
public class Subscriber
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Subscriber ID")]
    public int SubscriberId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    //set to money in DB
    [Display(Name = "Credits (Money owed to customer)")]
    private static decimal _Credits = 0;
    public decimal Credits { get { return _Credits; } set { _Credits = value; } }

    //set to money in DB
    [Display(Name = "Debits (Money owed to us)")]
    private static decimal _Debits = 0;
    public decimal Debits { get { return _Debits; } set { _Debits = value; } }

    public List<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }

    public List<Website> Websites { get; set; }

    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public List<SubscriberNote> SubscriberNotes { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see the subscriber has a bunch of related child entities. Here is my controller code which is  using an eager loading approach:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    { 
        var Subscriber = db.Subscribers
                           .Where(s => s.SubscriberId == id)
                           .Include(s => s.Users)
                           .Include(s => s.SubscriberNotes)
                           .Include(s => s.Orders)
                           .Include(s => s.Websites.Select(w => w.DomainNames))
                           .FirstOrDefault();

        return View(Subscriber);
    }
```

Ans here is my controller:

```
@model PpModels.Models.Subscriber

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Subscriber</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubscriberId)


    --deleted fro brevity--

    --Problem is below--

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users.FirstName)
    </div>    

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

MVC does not like model.Users.FirstName. How can I access these values? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to loop over this property, because it's a `List`. `Users` will not have the `FirstName` property but each user inside it will.

```
@foreach(var user in model.Users)
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => user.FirstName)
    </div>
    ....  
}
```